# Onclick event html button on serverside

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have this project given to me
the design of the project is on javaScript function the java script is call on the master page named Admin.Master.
The javascript funtion for design is shared by two webform rewardPoints.aspx and Transactions.aspx

Now my question is how can i able to add on click event in btnExportExcel inside Transaction.aspx

my java script funtion :

```
function TransSearchControls(page, cs) {
    var html = "";
    var display = (cs == "all") ? "inline-block" : "none";

    html += "<div class='col-xs-12 body'>";
    html += "<div class='col-xs-1 text-left' style='margin-top:5px'>Filter/s:</div>";
    html += "<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-2'><input type='text' class='input-sm form-control trans-controls-txt-search' placeholder='Search Employee' /></div>";
    html += "<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-2' style='display:" + display + "'><select class='input-sm slctSoaFilter form-control' >";
    html += "<option value='all' selected disabled>Select Transactions</option>";
    html += "<option value='all'>All</option>";
    html += "<option value='redeem'>Redeemed</option>";
    html += "<option value='earn'>Earned</option>";
    html += "</select></div>";
    html += "<div class='col-xs-1 text-right' style='margin-top:5px'>Date/s:</div>";
    html += "<div class='col-xs-5 col-sm-2'><input type='date' class='input-sm form-control dateFrom' /></div>";
    html += "<div class='col-xs-5 col-sm-2'><input type='date' class='input-sm form-control dateTo' /></div>";

    html += "<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-2'><button class='btn btn-sm btn-primary btnSearchTrans form-control' type='button' page='" + page + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Search</button></div>";
    html += "</div>";
    if (page == "Transactions") {
        html += "<div class='col-xs-12' style='margin-top:10px'>";
        html += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger' id='btnExportExcel'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-import'></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Export Excel</button>";
        html += "<span class='filename-container'></span>";
        html += "</div>";
    }
    if (page == "RewardPoints") {
        html += "<div class='col-xs-12' style='margin-top:10px'>";
        html += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' id='btnAddPoints'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign'></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add Points</button>&emsp;";
        html += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger' id='btnImportExcel'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-import'></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Import Excel</button>";
        html += "<span class='filename-container'></span>";
        html += "</div>";
    }
```

i want to add onclick event on the button inside

```
if (page == "Transactions")
```

this is how the function call in my Transaction.aspx

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".menu-title").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Transactions');
            $(".inner-menu-title").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;List of Employee Transactions');
            $(".transactions .main").addClass("active");

            TransSearchControls("Transactions", "all");
            var url = "&EmpName=&DateFrom=" + DefaultDate("from") + "&DateTo=" + DefaultDate("to");
            GetTransactions("Transactions", "all", url);


            $('.dateFrom').val(DefaultDate("from"));
            $('.dateTo').val(DefaultDate("to"));
        });
    </script>
```

I hope you understand what i mean i'm not good at English

Comment: Building the HTML as a long string is not a good idea. It makes for difficult debuging and it makes it more difficult for you to refactor etc. Try using `document.createElement()` and `element.appendChild()` instead. When you have your HTML elements stored in a variable you can easily ad an onClick callback for them with something along the line of `myElement.onClick = myCallback()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: yes it is difficult for me  the project is created by former developer and this project is was pass to me but sadly i have no background on java script and jquery.Can you be more specific on document.createElement()

Comment: I recommend the documentation that I linked, but to put it simple. You create a DOM element (HTML element) by passing the name of the element: `const myDiv = document.createElement('div')` or `const myButton = document.createElement('button')` etc. To then place the element in the page, you append it to an existing element with `element.appendChild()`.

Comment: Before you append the element, you can alter it programmatically like this: `myDiv.onclick = myFunction()` or `myDiv.style.background = 'blue'` and so on. You can find a reference to the Element object and it's properties and methods here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `onclick` event to the html button element.
So it would look something like this:

```
html += "<button type='button' onclick='TransactionsEvent()' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger' id='btnExportExcel'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-import'></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Export Excel</button>";
```

Then you must just update the function in the Javascript to match up:

```
function TransactionsEvent() {
    //do something here
}
```